# Can villagers trample my crops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When a village jumps on a patch of farm land will the seeds and the plants there be uprooted? If so, whats a good way to avoid this?

Comment: fence them out so they can't reach the farmland

Comment: Or you could KILL ALL THE VILLAGERS! A dead villager is a villager that won't be trampling your crops.

Comment: @ChargingPun Why kill them when you can imprison them? You don't want to lose those delicious trades...

Comment: @fredley I play on xbox, and they give me NOTHING! Death to villagers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes they will.

You can either fence off the crops, place blocks above them, or disable all crop trampling from mobs by using

```
/gamerule mobGriefing false
```

Comment: Note that wheat (at least, and maybe others too) needs one air block above the seedling or it won't grow.

Comment: Also note that disabling `gamerule mobGriefing` is a bit of overkill for just saving crops, as it would also prevent Creepers from blowing stuff up and Endermen stealing yo blox. Ain't saying this isn't cool :)